# Display only one result after join and CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these tables:

```
create table sales 
(
    "customer_id" VARCHAR(1),
    "order_date" DATE,
    "product_id" INTEGER
)
        
create table  menu 
(
    "product_id" INTEGER,            
    "product_name" VARCHAR(5),
    "price" INTEGER
)
    
CREATE TABLE members (
  "customer_id" VARCHAR(1),
  "join_date" DATE
);
```

And I needed the total items and amount spent for each member before they became a member.

So I did this:

```
WITH cte_1
AS (
    SELECT sal.customer_id AS customers_sales,
        sal. order_date,
        sal.product_id,
        mem.customer_id AS customers_members,
        mem.join_date,
        COUNT(sal.product_id) OVER (PARTITION BY sal.customer_id) AS count_purchases_by_customer
    FROM sales AS sal
    INNER JOIN members as mem
        ON sal.customer_id = mem.customer_id
    WHERE sal.order_date < mem.join_date
)
SELECT customers_sales
        , count_purchases_by_customer
        , SUM(price) OVER (PARTITION BY customers_sales) AS Amount_spend_by_customer
FROM cte_1
INNER JOIN menu
    ON cte_1.product_id = menu.product_id
```

With this result that is correct:

| customers_sales | count_purchases_by_customer | Amount_spend_by_customer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 25 |
| A | 2 | 25 |
| B | 3 | 40 |
| B | 3 | 40 |
| B | 3 | 40 |

But I'm trying to know how to get it to show me only one result per customer, since as you can see it's repeated. So only to see A = 25 and B = 40. But I can't make it work. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Where is the `members` table? Sample data would help also.

Comment: @Charlieface omg I'm losing my mind, haha I copy and pasted menu twice! I'll fix it right now! sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are over-complicating this. Just join the tables together, group it up and select the aggregations.

```sql
SELECT
  mem.customer_id,
  COUNT(*) AS count_purchases_by_customer,
  SUM(menu.price) AS Amount_spend_by_customer
FROM sales AS sal
JOIN members AS mem ON sal.customer_id = mem.customer_id
JOIN menu ON menu.product_id = sal.product_id
WHERE sal.order_date < mem.join_date
GROUP BY
  mem.customer_id;
```

I must say, your database design is flawed in many ways.

- `customer_id` shouldn't be `varchar(1)` that doesn't give you much scope.
- `varchar(1)` is silly anyway, you might as well have used `char(1)`.
- Equally `price` should probably be a `decimal`, and `join_date` should be `datetimeoffset`.
- You probably want to store a `sales.quantity` also.
- You should probably store the `price` in the `sales` table ie the price that `menu.price` was at the time the order was created. Otherwise price changes will change old orders.

Comment: I see, yeah that looks way better. Im still new and I didn't know you can do two joins at the same time like that haha. Thank you so much !

Comment: Oh also about the database design, this is not real, is from a website that gives you practice databases and questions to solve and get familiar with SQL, like this has only 10 purchases so is small and simple check if your answers are correct. Thanks again!